# How to replace values in rasters in directory 1 based on condition on other rasters in another directory?

Tags: raster, r

Having 10 raster files in one directory and another 10 rasters in another directory and both have the same dimensions.

directory 1:

```
    files1 <- list.files("C:\\2010", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
    s <- stack(files1)
```

directory 2:

```
 files2 <- list.files("C:\\2012", "*.envi", full.names = TRUE)
 s1 <- stack(files2)
```

I would like to filter s based on s1. 
I want to replace values in all layers in s by NA whenever corresponding layers in s1 have values greater than 0.6(corresponding pixels).

Answer (score 8):

Something like:

```
s1[s2 > 0.6] <- NA
```

This is the standard R way of doing things like this. You use `s2` to make a subset in `s1`, and then you replace that subset by `NA`. You might need to do some looping if rasterstacks do not support this directly.